# Weird glitch in listview in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

There are two weird glitches in my app

1. When using Listview, when I scroll down fast and up again, the first Item changes.

I didn't implement anything that would cause this, is it a glitch with 
Listview?

2. When updating the Listview, it fetches the data and when it goes to update it, it does the first 12 items right, then repeats them them again, then the first six again (for the total number of dorms)
   I can't find the a reason it repeated at 12 specifically here's my code

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnGetData;
private final String URL = "https://www.laundryalert.com/cgi-bin/urba7723/LMPage?Login=True";

private List<DormMachines> dorms;
private BaseAdapterDorm dormsAdapter;
private ListView dormsList;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set click listener for button
    btnGetData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContent);
    btnGetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new GetContent().execute();

        }
    });         dorms = new ArrayList<DormMachines>();

    dormsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    dormsAdapter = new BaseAdapterDorm(dorms, this);

    dormsList.setAdapter(dormsAdapter);

    setupListViewListener();
}

private void setupListViewListener() {
    dormsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            dorms.remove(position);
            dormsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

private class GetContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Getting Content");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        dorms.clear();

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            Element table = doc.getElementById("tableb");
            Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");

            // Removes table headers and whitespace at end
            rows.remove(0);
            rows.remove(0);
            rows.remove(30);

            for(Element row : rows) {
                int index = 0;
                DormMachines dorm = new DormMachines();
                for (Element rowData : row.getElementsByTag("td")) {
                    switch (index) {
                        case 1:
                            // Dorm Name
                            dorm.dormName = rowData.text();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            // Washers Free
                            dorm.washersFree = Integer.parseInt(rowData.text());
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            // Dryers Free
                            dorm.dryersFree = Integer.parseInt(rowData.text());
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            // Washers in Use
                            dorm.washersInUse = Integer.parseInt(rowData.text());
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            // Dryers In Use
                            dorm.dryersInUse = Integer.parseInt(rowData.text());
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;

                    }
                    index++;
                }
                dorms.add(dorm);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dormsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

BaseAdapterDorm class:

```
public class BaseAdapterDorm extends BaseAdapter {    
private List<DormMachines> list;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public BaseAdapterDorm(List<DormMachines> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    DormViewHolder dormViewHolder;

    if(view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_dorm_item, parent, false);

        dormViewHolder = new DormViewHolder();

        dormViewHolder.textViewDormName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dorm_item_name);
        dormViewHolder.textViewWasherAvail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_washers_avail);
        dormViewHolder.textViewWasherOccupied = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_washer_occupied);
        dormViewHolder.textViewDryersAvail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dryers_avail);
        dormViewHolder.textViewDryersOccupied = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dryers_occupied);

        dormViewHolder.textViewDormName.setText(list.get(position).dormName);
        dormViewHolder.textViewWasherAvail.setText(""+list.get(position).washersFree);
        dormViewHolder.textViewWasherOccupied.setText(""+list.get(position).washersInUse);
        dormViewHolder.textViewDryersAvail.setText(""+list.get(position).dryersFree);
        dormViewHolder.textViewDryersOccupied.setText(""+list.get(position).dryersInUse);
    }
    return view;
}

static class DormViewHolder {
    TextView textViewDormName;
    TextView textViewWasherAvail;
    TextView textViewWasherOccupied;
    TextView textViewDryersAvail;
    TextView textViewDryersOccupied;
}
```

}

Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8sp"
    tools:context="com.sergiodlz.jsoupexample.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get data"
            android:id="@+id/btnContent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

[The rest is on Github](https://github.com/Shaneneary/Laundry-View-UIUC)

Comment: obvious issue of not understanding how recycling works. read more listview tutorials.

Comment: It is obvious that you should add an else{} if view isn't null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListAdapters recycle their views (these views being the "entries" in the list). The number of views is arbitrary as far as we are usually concerned, but in this instance it is probably 12.

The idea is this... Once that arbitrary number of views has been created ( meaning all views have hit this if(view == null){...create/initialize} ), then every time you get a view at position Y, you will need to replace the contents of the view at position Y, otherwise you will see the content of the original entry that got slapped on that view.

Now to fix your problem, do something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    DormViewHolder dormViewHolder;

    if(view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_dorm_item, parent, false);

        dormViewHolder = new DormViewHolder();

        dormViewHolder.textViewDormName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dorm_item_name);
        dormViewHolder.textViewWasherAvail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_washers_avail);
        dormViewHolder.textViewWasherOccupied = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_washer_occupied);
        dormViewHolder.textViewDryersAvail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dryers_avail);
        dormViewHolder.textViewDryersOccupied = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_dryers_occupied);

        // Set the View Tag with the ViewHolder to save View properties.
        view.setTag(dormViewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        // Recycle the view (all View properties already set).
        dormViewHolder = (DormViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    dormViewHolder.textViewDormName.setText(list.get(position).dormName);
    dormViewHolder.textViewWasherAvail.setText(""+list.get(position).washersFree);
    dormViewHolder.textViewWasherOccupied.setText(""+list.get(position).washersInUse);
    dormViewHolder.textViewDryersAvail.setText(""+list.get(position).dryersFree);
    dormViewHolder.textViewDryersOccupied.setText(""+list.get(position).dryersInUse);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue in android, to overcome this you need to use viewholder inside your list view. The reason why it happens is because the list view recycles the views which causes this to happen